# Issue about the external display on macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, mojave

After I install macOS Mojave, the external display became very strange.

First of all, I have a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016), and I'm very sure I'm not in the mirror mode because I can put different applications on each display.

1. When I tried to switch between desktops on the external display (that's my main screen), the one on the MacBook will switch with it. This is very annoying because the desktop I can use now is very limited.
2. When I play the movie in the full-screen mode, the other display will be pure black.

These only happen after my update to Mojave, so I guess it is the problem of the system. Am I the only one have this problem?

Comment: Do you want to leave this as a yes no question? Some people will say yes - you're the only one - some people will say no - you're not the only one. I would encourage you to edit this to say what you want to happen. It seems you're really looking for mission control tutorial on Mojave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess, you have unchecked 'Displays have separate Spaces' in System prefs> Mission Control...
or, alternatively, you don't have more Spaces than screens, so they are forced to share.

Comment: Thanks so much. checked 'Displays have separate Spaces', and it is solved.